# mybatis nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException

Tags: java, mysql, spring, struts2, mybatis

I'm using struts2-spring,spring-mybatis. I get this error:

`12:21:18,499 DEBUG insertar:46 - ooo Using Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@c0b6]
 12:21:18,499 DEBUG insertar:46 - ==>  Preparing: { CALL INSERTAR_REGISTRO(?,?,?)} 
 12:21:18,516 DEBUG insertar:46 - ==> Parameters: 10302770(String), 2013-10-18(String), 2013-10-18 01:30:00(String)
 12:21:18,531 TRACE insertar:50 - <==    Columns: VID, VENTRADA, VSALIDA, @VPROX, @INSERTAR, @ESTADO, @CONTADOR
 12:21:18,531 TRACE insertar:50 - <==        Row: 69, 2013-10-18 07:15:00.0, 2013-10-18 07:20:00.0, <<BLOB>>, 1, 2, 14
 **nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: Error instantiating void with invalid types () or values (). Cause: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: void.<init>() # org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: Error instantiating void with invalid types () or values (). Cause: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: void.<init>()**`

When I test in workbench there's no problem, for example: `CALL INSERTAR_REGISTRO('10302770','2013-10-18','2013-10-18 01:30:00')`; but in my app get exception.

My procedure `PROCEDURE INSERTAR_REGISTRO(IN PNNUMEROID varchar(8), IN PDFECHAEVENTO varchar(10), IN PNFECHAHORA varchar(19))`.

My service class:

```
@Service
@Scope("request")
public class RegistroServiceImp implements RegistroService {

@Autowired
RegistroMapper registroMapper;

@Transactional
public void registrar(Registro registro, String fecha_hora)
        throws Exception {
    String[] arrayFch = registro.getFecha_evento().split("/");
    String nuevaFch = arrayFch[2] + "-" + arrayFch[1] + "-" + arrayFch[0];
    System.out.println(nuevaFch);
    registroMapper.insertar(registro.getNumero_id(), nuevaFch, nuevaFch
            + " " + fecha_hora);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I solution my problem only remove my select of information. I think that problem is because for my variable @VPROX that have form SET @VPROX = 0 and later I SET @VPROX = VSALIDA, this variable VSALIDA have form DECLARE VSALIDA DATETIME. I don't know because ibatis my return the variable @VPROX like `<<BLOB>>` and at workbench like datetime.